# Going to the start of insert command on exit

Tags: insert-mode, escape

Hi Vi StackExchange,

### A Picture of what I want

Say I have the following in my buffer:

```
foo("a", "bar")
```

And I am in normal mode with my point on `b` in `bar`.

Now I want to insert some characters, say `xyz` before bar. So I press:

`ixyz<esc>`

Then that leaves my point on z.

---

**What I want is something that I can press to go to the *start* of the last insert some magic key `<magic key>` such that:**

`ixyz<esc><magic key>`

Leaves me with my point at `x`.

I will then proceed to map the composition `<esc><magic key>` as a secondary exit for me to use.

Comment: Why do you want to go to the start of the insert? A clearer understanding of what is being accomplished might help design the solution (`gi` and the `.` mark came to mind but dont fit your needs)

Comment: There's the [`^` mark](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%5E), but that will leave you on the `b`, which *is* where the cursor was before you started insert mode, but with a different logic than what you describe (not absolute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing an insert the marks `'[` and `']` are set to the start character and *just past the end* of the inserted text.

A map like this should work:

```
inoremap <c-l> <esc>`[
```

which just leaves insert mode then goes to the `'[` mark.

You can also go to the mark without leaving insert mode;

```
inoremap <c-l> <c-o>`[
```